# Is there a Latin term for the concept of "ad infinitum", but in reverse?

Tags: phrase-requests, latin

When someone says that a process happens *ad infinitum*, it tends to imply that the process happens again and again, carrying on into the future. But how do you talk about something that **has been happening** again and again, back into the past, i.e. an infinite regression? Is there a Latin phrase which encapsulates this meaning?

Comment: I like the question.  A Latin phrase I can use when I complain about a proposed change, instead of saying "We have always done it this way!"

Comment: :') If only there were such. Latin expressions are the ne plus ultra of awesome.

Comment: The concept of *ad infinitum* in reverse is *ad infinitum*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider *recurrent, perennial,* and *perpetual*.

*[Recurrent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recurrent#Adjective)* has senses including  “Recurring time after time” and “Running back toward its origin” that taken together might suffice.

Although the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=perennial) of *[perennial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perennial#Adjective)* includes an element *annus*, or “year”, perennial also has (since 1750) a sense of enduring or permanent, and wiktionary shows figurative senses that include  “Continuing without cessation or intermission; perpetual; permanent; unceasing; never failing” and “Recurrent; appearing or recurring again and again”.

Macmillandictionary.com shows senses of *[perpetual](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/perpetual)* including  “happening so often that you become annoyed as a result [eg] *He soon grew tired of her perpetual demands for money*” and  “literary, continuing all the time [eg] *Many people live in perpetual fear of losing their jobs*”.

Also note: With its sense of “Endlessly; for ever; neverendingly”, *[ad infinitum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad_infinitum)* perhaps can refer to a perpetual series of cycles in the past as well as in the future.

Comment: +1, but I can't actually upvote yet (I'll be very happy when I reach 200 reputation on an SE website and don't have to go through this reputation fuss on every site.)
I think endlessly is probably the best word in this situation :).

Comment: There is the word *sempiternal*

Comment: @GEdgar - that is a beautiful word.

Answer (score 8):

How about *ab initio*?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_initio) has it as:

> L., lit. "**from the beginning**", from ablative case of initium "entrance, beginning", related to verb inire "to go into, enter upon, begin".[2]

It's often used to signal that a certain activity has to start again from the top, but perhaps it matches what you're after.

Comment: I'm not sure it does, because the concept I'm trying to describe is going **to** the beginning, not from. But then I've never heard the phrase "ad initio", and a Google search turns up nothing, so there may not be a word for it.

Comment: Well, since things don't tend to go forward, backwards in time, perhaps there won't be a common term for it. :)

Comment: Perhaps not! Oh well.

Comment: You can't find *"ad initio"* because it's grammatically wrong; *"initio"* is in the wrong case. It's *"ad initial"* and *"ab initio"*. Both of these phrases can be found using Google. Unfortunately, *"ad"* means either *"at"* or *"to"*, so the most common meaning of *"ad initium"* is "at the beginning". But it is how you would say *"to the beginning"* in Latin.

Comment: Okay. I guess there's no established and precedented term for the meaning I want, but that's what I expected, so no matter. Ad initium would do if I really had to use it, so thank you :).

Comment: Re my above comment. It's not "ad initial". The stupid spell corrector doesn't know Latin, and "corrected" "ad initium" to "ad initial".

Comment: Aha, that's okay, I knew what you meant ;).

Comment: 'Infinity' by definition has no beginning nor end. So how can it relate to past or future? I am no Latin scholar so I cannot comment on the precise meaning of *ad infinitum'*. 

But could we not complain, if driven to hyperbole, that we had been waiting *ad infinitum* for the goods to arrive?

Comment: @PeterShor: Spank it! Anyway, I agree.

Comment: @WS2, actually I agree that that does sound grammatically valid. I was trying to express the philosophical idea that the universe has existed forever, which is one meaning of the term "infinite regression". I guess I could just say "the universe has existed *ad infinitum*"

Comment: The exact phrase I was trying to make work was "who is to say that the universe has not been contracting and expanding ___" and in the blank I wanted to express the meaning "since the beginning of time" in a single word.

Comment: Or "the universe has existed *ab infinito*" — since infinity — although i don't know Latin, so I don't know whether that's a proper use of the term.